# PHP - Problems reading a text file

Tags: javascript, php

So recently I improved my code and managed to save a javascript variable through PHP(AJAX) to a txt file. The txt is working and it gets the javascript number but I'm having problems retrieving the number on the txt file.

PHP code:

```
<?php
 $file_content = file_get_contents('num.txt');
?>
```

Javascript code:

```
function recnum(){
document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = '<?php echo $file_content; ?>';
}
```

So after this, the number on the html page stays the same (1) and doesn't change.

Comment: What is the content of the text file?

Comment: Why should the number change? You overwrite the text file? How? Have you verified that the content of the file changes? Have you refreshed the webpage? [F5]

Comment: Yes the file is changing correctly. The content is a number and it's always changing when I press the button, but the error is that I can't read that number on the text file.

Comment: If the result is `1` then the script has read something... namely `1`. Check that you're actually reading the file you wrote, and again: Make sure the page is refreshed properly (and not cached).

Comment: The result is 1 because the output on the HTML page is  <p id="num">1</p> It is not getting the new value given by the text file.

Comment: Is there anyway I can avoid the javascript, like put directly the php into the output?

Comment: I suspect there may be a misunderstanding about [client and server-side programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) here.

Comment: " It is not getting the new value given by the text file"...if you updated the text file _after_ you loaded the page then naturally it will not read the new value. The value of PHP `$file_content` variable was injected into the HTML/JS by PHP at the time that PHP created the content and sent it to the browser. So you will end up with JS code like `document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = '1'` in your browser. When you run the JS `recnum()` function it simply repeats inserting that hard-coded value. The PHP code does not get executed again until you make another request to re-load the page.

Comment: Are you executing recnum(), because this js code is only a function declaration.

Comment: IMHO, use jQuery and an Ajax call to fetch the latest value from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put data directly into HTML avoiding Javascript then you can try the code following:

```
<div id="num"><?php echo $file_content; ?></div>
```

Note: I assumed that you have div with `num` id already in html.

**UPDATE:** Based on your comment. You have defined variable after it being used. So define it first and then use like in modified code below:

```
<?php
$file = "num.txt";
//Path to your *.txt file 
$contents = file($file);
$file_content = implode($contents);
echo $file_content;
?> 

<html> 
    <body> 
    <head> 
        <title> Botão </title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <div id="num"><?php echo $file_content; ?></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Is variable `$file_content` defined in same file where you are using it?

Comment: <?php
 $file = "num.txt"; //Path to your *.txt file
$contents = file($file);
$file_content = implode($contents);
echo $file_content;
?>

Comment: Is there any `if else` conditions or something like that? Because it should not give `Undefined variable` if variable is there.

Comment: No that is the full php code. Don't have if else in any of my code.

Comment: Any other error that might be present? This is the full code now:7

Comment: <html>
<body>
<head>
  <title> Botão </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 </head>

   <div id="num"><?php echo $file_content; ?></div>
 <?php
 $file = "num.txt"; //Path to your *.txt file
$contents = file($file);
$file_content = implode($contents);
echo $file_content;
?>
</html>

Comment: Worked. Thanks.